# PHP Multidimensional array - Remove part duplicates and add up

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array like so:

```
array(4) {
    [0] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(15)
        "One" 
        [1] => string(5)
        "11:31"
    }
  [1] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(4)
        "Two" 
        [1] => string(5)
        "11:31"
    }
  [2] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(15)
        "Three" 
        [1] => string(5)
        "11:31"
    }
  [3] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(4)
        "One" 
        [1] => string(5)
        "11:31"
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the ones with the first value removed but added up together. So it would end up like so:

```
array(3) {
    [0] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(15)
        "One" 
        [1] => string(5)
        "22:62"
    }
  [1] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(4)
        "Two" 
        [1] => string(5)
        "11:31"
    }
  [2] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(15)
        "Three" 
        [1] => string(5)
        "11:31"
    }
}
```

Note the last 'One' has been removed and the second value in the array has been added up there from two 11:31's to 22:62. I hope that makes sense.

Is there something or a specific function I should look at to push me in the right direction? Any help much appreciated.

This is not just a straight up removing duplicates from what I can tell, as none are ever exactly the same although the second values are in this example, they won't be in live data.

Comment: Can you provide a formatted array? The one we can just copy and paste on our editor. :)

Comment: When you say "added up", do you mean as times or just as raw numbers? `22:62` feels a bit strange.

Comment: @iainn it is time indeed, but I figured I could calculate the time from the raw numbers either way and it seemed like an easier question!

Comment: @Eddie I am not sure what you mean I tried to <pre> the array but copying into Stackoverflow removes the formatting

Comment: Because it needs double new lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: @z3nth10n Definitely not a duplicate, considering I am not just removing duplicate values..

Comment: also thanks for the improvement of the array edit z3nth - @Eddie

Comment: You need `22:62` or `23:02`?

Comment: @Syscall 23:02 would be perfect, but I guess we could recalculate the time from 22:62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a loop and group elements into a new array using key `[0]`. It the key doesn't exists in the new array, simply add the new array. Otherwise, you could parse the existing value to add the new value:

```
$array = [
  ["One", "11:31"],
  ["Two", "11:31"],
  ["Three", "11:31"],
  ["One", "11:31"],
];

$out = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
  // if $item[0] is not an existing key,
  if (!isset($out[$item[0]])) {
    // add $item as-is
    $out[$item[0]] = $item;
  } else {

    // parse current time
    list($h1, $m1) = explode(':', $item[1]);
    $m1 += $h1 * 60;

    // parse existing time
    list($h2, $m2) = explode(':', $out[$item[0]][1]);
    $m1 += $m2 + $h2 * 60;

    // compute new time
    $h = floor($m1 / 60);
    $out[$item[0]][1] = sprintf("%02d:%02d", $h, $m1-$h*60);
  }
}
// array_values removes 'named' keys. 
print_r(array_values($out));
```

Output (condensed):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array ([0] => One [1] => 23:02)
    [1] => Array ([0] => Two [1] => 11:31)
    [2] => Array ([0] => Three [1] => 11:31)
)
```

Comment: @Skintest, I've updated the answer (corrected) - see working example: https://3v4l.org/D8H21